# MVC4:Prevent the user to type and navigate any ControllerName/ActionName in the address bar

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC application, I dont want any user to type in the address bar of the browser and navigate to any controller action directly.Can I enable this for the whole application?if yes ,How? Can you please let me know the concept name ?

Also I dont want to do that through `Request.URLReferrer` because it has its own security risks (per [Avoiding user to navigate to a view by entering url in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835462/avoiding-user-to-navigate-to-a-view-by-entering-url-in-the-browser?lq=1))

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **Custom Action Filter Attributes**, See :

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters

****Updated:**

As **Parsanna**  mentioned in comment,

You can use the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute on your action method to make sure it's not called directly, or use the `ControllerContext.IsChildAction` property inside your action to determine if you want to redirect.

See :[Asp.net mvc How to prevent browser from calling an action method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407172/asp-net-mvc-how-to-prevent-browser-from-calling-an-action-method)

Comment: But what should I write in there ? Anything that can be specified in Controller or in GLobal.asax ??

Comment: you need to create custom action filter attribute and will apply that attribute on every action.

Comment: Can you determine if the user directly typed an address in their browser address bar vs followed a link in the application? I don't think you can...how does an action filter enable this?

Comment: like this:
[CustomActionFilter]
public class StoreController : Controller
{
    ...
}

Comment: @Ehsaan, Are you talking about something mentioned in the below link ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407172/asp-net-mvc-how-to-prevent-browser-from-calling-an-action-method

Comment: If I use `[ChildActionOnly]` then users with AJAX post mayn't be able to access that (http 500 error..) .More importantly if I use Child Action attribute, then I cannot use get that while referring though `Html.ActionLink` even..

Comment: hmm, then you can do something with action filter

Comment: Yes. Thats the only option left(seems like)..Can you please guide me achieving this through actionfilter ?

Comment: first you see how to write a custom action filter, there are exmples available google it